Do you know any Guru who is learned in 4 vedas and is a Bramha Jnani?
Do you know any Guru who is learned in all the 4 vedas and is a Bramha Jnani.

साधु दर्शन एवं सत्प्रसंग - भाग 1-2, भाग 3, भाग 4
This set of books mentions forty saints of recent times. You will have to trace their lineages.
Reference article - https://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A5_%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%9C
